# Spring Security LDAP Active Directory Connection Periodically Refused

Tags: spring-mvc, active-directory, connection, ldap

I have set up LDAP Active Directory authentication for a Spring MVC application that I am configuring. I have been able to log in, and a majority of the time authentication occurs successfully. However, every so often, I will get a Connection Refused error. The timing for this seems to be sporadic and resolves each time within ten to fifteen minutes. I have done some research and have found that other have also had this problem. However, I have not been able to find a solution or a hint as to what may be causing it. If anyone could point me in the right direction on this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this question about Spring Security LDAP authentication?

Comment: Yes, this is about Spring Security LDAP authentication. I will update the question.

Comment: I wasn't aware there is a special class for AD authentication. The described behavior is strange. I suggest you to sniff the network communication (e.g. by using Wireshark) and check what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get an answer to this question from a coworker. He had me switch to another server and the problem seems to be resolved. He gave me the reason that the server I had been hitting was being overloaded.